# Multiple forms of citation call-outs to one and the same bib item?

Tags: citing, natbib

Let's use the following simple example

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Test}
According to \citet{AB00} we have that...

According to Paper I we have that...

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Atuhors}{2000}]{AB00} Author A., Author B., 2000, Journal, 01, 001 (Paper I)

\end{thebibliography}    
\end{document}
```

My question is the following: How can I add a citation call-out (preferably as a hyperlink) of the form "Paper I" in the main text, so as it is associated with the reference `AB00`?

Comment: BTW, `\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Authors}{2000}]{AB00}...` is needless complicated if you can be sure to be using the `natbib` package. With `natbib` loaded, it suffices to write `\bibitem[Authors(2000)]{AB00}...`

Comment: @Mico: Most likely `biblatex` would be better anyway

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - My impression was that the OP loads the `natbib` package but, for whatever reason, creates the bibliography by hand. (For sure, `\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Atuhors}{2000}]{AB00}` is *not* generated by BibTeX/natbib.) If this impression is correct, the OP would almost certainly be better off learning how to use either BibTeX or biblatex/biber.

Comment: @Mico: I am no bib - related stuff expert, but `natbib` is still not compatible with `biblatex`, as far as I know?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - That's correct: If `biblatex` is loaded, `natbib` should *not* be loaded as well. (When using `biblatex`, it's possible to load the package with the  `natbib=true` option in order to be able to make use of commands such as `\citet` and `\citep`.) Either way, I don't think the OP's sample formatted bib entry was created by either `biblatex` or `natbib`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `\defcitealias{AB00}{Paper 1}` and `\citetalias{AB00}` is the correct tool here:

```
% \pdfoutput=1

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{}

\author{}

\date{}

\maketitle

\defcitealias{AB00}{Paper 1}

\section{Test}

According to \citet{AB00} we have that...

According to \citetalias{AB00} we have that...
\clearpage

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Authors}{2000}]{AB00} Author A., Author B., 2000, Journal, 01, 001 (Paper I)

\end{thebibliography}    

\end{document}
```

[image]